# Upgrading to Worklight 6.2

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I am facing issue with upgrading to Worklight 6.2.
Please find the error below:

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain how is this related to upgrading to 6.2? Studio? External server? project setup? something to work with......

Answer (score 1):

I guess you see this when starting your 6.2 server? It's because you have your 6.1 server still running. The clash on the dt_socket will cause the JVM to exit very early in startup.

You may run them both by adjusting the ports in one of them.

The dt_socket is specified in the server's jvm options:

```
      -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=10777
```

the remaining ports are specified in the server.xml

Comment: Thanks, yes it was in use. restarting the system worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the problem without restarting your system.

Just type this in your commande line ( Linux, Mac OS) to look for process Id Worklight is using and kill it. Then go back to your eclipse and start your server. I'll work like a charm. Here the commande Line :

```
ps -A | grep worklight
kill -9 57184
```

(57184)  : is the process Id, for my case I found 2 processes so killed the both.