# Server Worklight Development Server failed to start

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have install latest version of IBM Worklight on Marketplace of eclipse juno. I have create a new project and then run my project **Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server**. then i have face an error on the server. Please Help me.

Thanks

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
objc[42627]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
/Users/apple/Downloads/eclipse 2/plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.2.0.00-20140904-1709/liberty/wlp/bin/server: line 710: 42627 Abort trap: 6           "${JAVA_CMD}" "$@"
```

Comment: Please to refer to this answer, It may solve your issue : [transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870423/upgrading-to-worklight-6-2/33278306#33278306)

Answer (score 1):

Your Log says Address Already in use. Restart your eclipse. Make sure process is killed.
Either your eclipse did not exit gracefully or some other application is using the port.
If some application is using the port go to server view of eclipse, expand "worklight development server" and change port in "server.xml" file. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message it is clearly saying that address already in use , this means the port number id using java.exe in background process.so this time if you stop server also this will not release.For this please do the following.
1.Download TCPView from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx for windows.
2.Install TcpView , after that you will find the port number say 10080.Right click on port number and end process.Now Clean the project and run the server.

Hope this helps.