# IBM Worklight server not working after update 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

IBM Worklight server not working after update 6.3. The error states `Server MobileFirst Development Server failed to start`.

Any thoughts about this error? Added a image for reference.

[image]

On console, i am getting the error

`FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]`

Comment: Do you see any helpful messages in the Console view in Eclipse?

Comment: On console, i am getting the error

FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]

Comment: Agreed with djna's answer. Try to locate and kill your existing server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transport already in use: could you have an old copy of the server still running. Unless I can spot the process and kill it I'd restart my machine.

Comment: Please to refer to this answer, It may solve your issue : [transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870423/upgrading-to-worklight-6-2/33278306#33278306)